# Conversion of long to decimal in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, decimal, type-conversion

I have a value stored in a variable which is of type "long".

```
long fileSizeInBytes = FileUploadControl.FileContent.Length;
Decimal fileSizeInMB = Convert.ToDecimal(fileSizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024));
```

I want to convert the fileSizeInBytes to decimal number rounded up to 2 decimal places (like these: 1.74, 2.45, 3.51) But i'm not able to get the required result. I'm only getting single digit with no decimal places as result. Can some one help me with that ??.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: long is just a big integer, it has nothing past the decimal point.  Give an example of what you're getting and what you're expecting, I think you're confusing long with another type.

Comment: @Milimetric as suggested by robbrit i tried to do what he has suggested. For example if i divide 20364702/(1024.0m * 1024.0m) this is the result i'm getting: 19.4212932586669921875M But i want the result to be 19.42. I want the result to be rounded to two decimal places. How can i do that ??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Decimal fileSizeInMB = Convert.ToDecimal(fileSize) / (1024.0m * 1024.0m);
```

What you're doing is dividing the filesize by an integer, which results in an *integer*, not a decimal. Any remainder left over will be chopped off.

Comment: @But i want the result to be rounded to decimal places. If i divide 20364702/(1024.0m * 1024.0m) this is the result i'm getting: 19.4212932586669921875M But i want the result to be 19.42. How can i get that ??

Comment: @user653622 you can use Math.Round( fileSizeInMB,2) is one way

Answer (score 2):

I don't see `fileSize` declared anywhere - but Im going to assume it's a long. So `fileSize / (1024 * 1024)` is forced up to a long value which doesn't hold any decimal places so you get something like:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(someLongValue)
```

Which won't have any decimal places. Convert the division to a double (or some other decimal) first before passing it to `Convert.ToDecimal`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little late but here you have more or less everything you need for filesizes watts etc

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{ 

    class Program
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Formats the given size to the order of magniture given
        /// Order is 1 for KB, 2 for MB etc up to 8, after that you get exponents for the same notations
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="size">The total size in bytes</param>
        /// <param name="order">+1 for each 1024 B,M,... 0 for nothing</param>
        /// <param name="unit">Usually you will want B for bytes denotation, but maybe "bit" or "bi" or W for watt</param>
        /// <param name="decimal_places">Number of desired decimal places</param>
        /// <param name="add_space">Separate KB MB etc from the number with a space?</param>
        /// <returns>Formatted size</returns>
        public static string FormatSize(string unit, double size, int order, int decimal_places, bool add_space) {

            string[] suffixes = new string[] {"", "K","M","G","T","P","E","Z","Y"};

            int exponent = order - 8 > 0 ? order - 8 : 0;
            order -= exponent;

            string suffix = suffixes[order];

            while (order > 0) {
                size /= 1024;
                order--;
            }

            string sDecimals = new String('0', decimal_places);
            string sExponent = exponent != 0 ? "E" + exponent : "";
            string dot = decimal_places > 0 ? "." : "";

            return size.ToString("#,##0" + dot + sDecimals + sExponent) + (add_space ? " " : "") + suffix + unit;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] Args)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            string sz;
            sz = FormatSize("B", 1024, 1, 0, false);
            Console.WriteLine(sz);
            sz = FormatSize("B", 1024*1024 + 512, 1, 0, true);
            Console.WriteLine(sz);
            sz = FormatSize("W", 1024 * 1024 + 512, 1, 2, true);
            Console.WriteLine(sz);
            sz = FormatSize("B", 1024 * 1024 + 512, 2, 2, true);
            Console.WriteLine(sz);
            sz = FormatSize("B", 1024 * 1024 * 1024 + 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 2, 3, 0, false);
            Console.WriteLine(sz);
            sz = FormatSize("bit", 1024 * 1024 * 1024 + 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 2, 3, 1, false);
            Console.WriteLine(sz);
            sz = FormatSize("B", 1024 * 1024 * 1024 + 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 2 - 1, 3, 2, false);
            Console.WriteLine(sz);
            sz = FormatSize("Ω", 1024 * 1024 * 1024 + 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 2 - 1, 3, 1, false);
            Console.WriteLine(sz);
            sz = FormatSize("B", 1024 * 1024 * 1024 + 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 2 - 10000000, 3, 2, false);
            Console.WriteLine(sz);
            sz = FormatSize("B", 1024 * 1024 * 1024 + 1024 * 1024 * 1024 / 2 - 1, 3, 0, false);
            Console.WriteLine(sz);
            sz = FormatSize("bit", 1208925819614629174706176f, 9, 2, true);
            Console.WriteLine(sz);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some output:

```
1KB
1,025 KB
1,024.50 KW
1.00 MB
2GB
1.5Gbit
1.50GB
1.5GΩ
1.49GB
1GB
1.00E1 Ybit
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a function i use to display file size

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// <summary>
        /// Formats from bytes to KB,MB,GB,TB 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="number">Bytes to format</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string AutoFileSize(long number)
        {
            double tmp = number;
            string suffix = " B ";
            if (tmp > 1024) { tmp = tmp / 1024; suffix = " KB"; }
            if (tmp > 1024) { tmp = tmp / 1024; suffix = " MB"; }
            if (tmp > 1024) { tmp = tmp / 1024; suffix = " GB"; }
            if (tmp > 1024) { tmp = tmp / 1024; suffix = " TB"; }
            return tmp.ToString("n") + suffix;
        }
```